# Average Population of Each Continent

Tags: mysql, sql

am trying to write the query for the following requirement.Given two tables, City and Country whose description are given below. Print the name of all continents (key: Country.Continent) along with the average City population rounded down to nearest integer.

```
City

+-------------+----------+
| Field       | Type     |
 +-------------+----------+
| ID          | int(11)  |
| Name        | char(35) |
| CountryCode | char(3)  |
| District    | char(20) |
| Population  | int(11)  |
+-------------+----------+
```

Country

```
+----------------+-------------+
| Field          | Type        |
+----------------+-------------+
| Code           | char(3)     |
| Name           | char(52)    |
| Continent      | char(50)    |
| Region         | char(26)    |
| SurfaceArea    | float(10,2) |
| IndepYear      | smallint(6) |
| Population     | int(11)     |
| LifeExpectancy | float(3,1)  |
| GNP            | float(10,2) |
| GNPOld         | float(10,2) |
| LocalName      | char(45)    |
| GovernmentForm | char(45)    |
| HeadOfState    | char(60)    |
| Capital        | int(11)     |
| Code2          | char(2)     |
+----------------+-------------+
```

PS #1: City.CountryCode and Country.Code is same key.
PS #2: Continent without cities should not be included in output.

I have tried the following query, but it seems something wrong in it,
please correct me.

```
select Country.Continent,round(avg(City.population),0) from City
join Country
on City.CountryCode=Country.Code
where City.ID<>NULL
Group by Country.Continent;
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Try `where City.ID is not null`

Comment: Hint:  The average of the city population is *not* the population of the continent.

Comment: No error message, but its not returning any rows, even though there are rows that it should return.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, the avg city population of each continent means the avg population of each continent right?

Answer (score 2):

```
select country.continent,floor(avg(city.population))
from country inner join city
on country.Code=city.countrycode 
group by country.continent;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select country.continent,floor(avg(city.population))
 from city,country
where city.countrycode=country.code
group by country.continent;
```

Works perfectly without errors

[image]

Comment: I actually find the logic of your answer the easiest to follow. Particularly if you order it as below. Thanks!

SELECT COUNTRY.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CITY.POPULATION))
FROM COUNTRY, CITY
WHERE COUNTRY.CODE = CITY.COUNTRYCODE
GROUP BY COUNTRY.CONTINENT;

Answer (score 1):

I used the following query for this question:

```
Select COUNTRY.Continent, FLOOR(AVG(CITY.POPULATION)) 
From CITY join COUNTRY on CITY.CountryCode = COUNTRY.Code  
Group by country.continent
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select country.continent,floor(avg(city.population)) from country,city 
where country.code = city.countrycode
group by country.continent;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

It is caused by `City.ID<>NULL`. The result will always be `null` and no rows will appear.

Instead, use `where City.ID is not null`.

Cf.: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/working-with-null.html

Example:

`select null <> null` gives `null`

while

`select null is not null` gives `false`

As you can see, `null` can not be compared using the =, <, > operators, even with itself.

Same for

`select 1 <> null` gives `null`, but

`select 1 is not null` results in `true`

Answer (score 0):

```
select country.continent,floor(avg(city.population))
 from city,country
where city.id is NOT NULL
  and city.countrycode=country.code
group by country.continent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNTRY.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CITY.POPULATION))
FROM CITY INNER JOIN COUNTRY ON CITY.COUNTRYCODE=COUNTRY.CODE
GROUP BY COUNTRY.CONTINENT;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
select country.continent,
   floor(avg(city.population)) from country,city where country.code=city.countrycode group by country.continent;
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.Continent , FLOOR(AVG(c.Population))
FROM Country p, City c 
WHERE p.Code = C.CountryCode 
GROUP BY p.Continent ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here the solution which I came up with:

```js
select co.continent,
floor(sum(ci.population) / count(ci.name))
from 
country co join city ci on ci.countrycode = co.code 
group by co.continent;
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select country.continent ,truncate(avg(city.population),0) as dd
from city
left join country on city.countrycode=country.code
group by country.continent having country.continent is not NULL
order by dd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in oracle -

```sql
select cu.continent
     , floor(avg(c.population)) 
  from city c 
  join country cu 
    on c.countrycode = cu.code 
 group by cu.continent;
```

[image: The output you will be getting is -]

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following code using Oracle.

```
SELECT CO.Continent, FLOOR(AVG((C.Population)))
FROM CITY C 
     INNER JOIN COUNTRY CO ON C.CountryCode = CO.Code
     GROUP BY CO.Continent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I used following for mysql:

```
SELECT COUNTRY.CONTINENT, FLOOR(AVG(CITY.POPULATION))
FROM CITY
JOIN COUNTRY
ON CITY.COUNTRYCODE=COUNTRY.CODE
GROUP BY COUNTRY.CONTINENT;
```

Answer (score 0):

By using mysql, it is possible to perform a subquery to extract the desired columns:

```
select 
     continent,
     floor(avg(population))
from (select * 
       from city
            inner join (select code, continent from country) a 
       on city.countrycode=a.code) b
group by continent;
```

Answer (score -2):

```sql
select country.continent, FLOOR (AVG (city.population))
from country
join city on country.code=city.countrycode
group by country.continent;
```